# NSURLConnection and different ways of making asynchronous requests

Tags: ios, http, rest, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I need to communicate with RESTful services either through HTTP and HTTPS. I am reading some examples about performing asynchronous requests by means of the `NSURLConnection` class, and some of them use the `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method, and other use the `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` method and implements the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods. I'm not able to make clear what implications each of these approaches has, if difference is only in implementation but performance and results are the same, or if one of the approaches is better or more correct than the other...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two differences that are usually key.

- First, the return type of both methods. `[NSURLConnection
  sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` has a return type
  of `void` which means you cannot capture the NSURLConnection e.g. in
  a property, so you lose quite some control over it, i.e. you can not
  `[NSURLConnection cancel]` it. On the other hand, [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:] does return the connection back to you, so you retain full control.
- Second, if you are downloading a large file, the block based method
  will load the data into memory and 'deliver' it when the block
  executes. Presuming a small RESTful answer, this might be ok for you.
  However if you are downloading a large file you might want to write
  the incoming data directly into a file handle to reduce memory
  consumption. For this you need the delegate method
  `[NSURLConnectionDataDelegate connection:didReceiveData:]`. Sadly the
  [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation is not readily linked in the current Apple documentation.
  If you set yourself to be the delegate of the NSURLConnection, those
  methods will be called.

Hope this helps.